# My pseudo-3D program is drawing a dot instead of a line

Tags: java, graphics, 3d, draw

My one class pseudo-3D program is making a dot at 0,0 instead of a line. I see no reason why it should be doing this. I am relatively new to java. This is also the first time posting a question. If my code is messy, that is why.
I envisioned this code to be able to make a pseudo-3D that could be shifted on the x, y, and z-axis by inputing a new location with the Calculate3D(x, y, z) method. Thanks for helping!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class threeD extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public static int WIDTH = 400;
    public static int HEIGHT = 400;
    int counter = 0;
    int x1, y1, x2, y2, FOV = 150, xpo = 0, ypo = 0, zpo = 80, fx1 = 20, fy1 = 20;

    private JFrame window;
    private Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new threeD().start();
    }

    public void start() {
        window = new JFrame();
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        window.pack();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

        timer = new Timer(1000 / 60, this);
    }

    public void Calculate3D(int x, int y, int z) {
        x1 = fx1;
        y1 = fy1;
        x2 = FOV * ((x + xpo) / (z + zpo));
        y2 = FOV * ((y + ypo) / (z + zpo));
        fx1 = x2;
        fy1 = y2;
        counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
            g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Calculate3D(20, 20, 0);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: The biggest problem is that all your numbers are integers and your integer division produces 0 quickly. Use `double` instead. Apart from that, it is not clear what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your `actionPerformed`, and thus the `Calculate3D` is not called. If you call the method in e.g. `start`, you will see that the line is drawn. If you intend to draw the line on button click etc., see this [Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for further information.